# loop in Angular js script

Tags: angularjs

```
<?php
$total=0;
for($i1=1; $i1<=6; $i1++) {
    for($i2=$i1+1; $i2<= 6; $i2++) {
        echo $i1.", ".$i2."<br>";
        $total=$total+1;
    }
}
echo "<br>Total = ".$total;
```

Please Convert this php code to angular js code

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="pair in pairs">
    {{pair}}
  </div>
  Total = {{total}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pairs = [];
  $scope.total = 0

  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j <= 6; j++) {
      $scope.pairs.push(i + ", " + j);
      $scope.total = $scope.total + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/scb08Lxe/.

So in one file it goes like that:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pairs = [];
  $scope.total = 0

  for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j <= 6; j++) {
      $scope.pairs.push(i + ", " + j);
      $scope.total = $scope.total + 1;
    }
  }
}
</script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="pair in pairs">
    {{pair}}
  </div>
  Total = {{total}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain Javascript.

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (var j = i+1; j <= 6; j++) {
        alert(i, j);
        total = total + 1;
    }
}
alert(total);
```

That was a weird question actually. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks for reply but can you please explain how to print instead of alert

Comment: See @lukaZawi answer

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is Javascript too, so you can just do this

PO Javascript

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j <= 6; j++) {
    console.info(i, j);
    total = total + 1;
  }
}
console.info(total);
```

Angularjs way :

For angularJS you can check the links above to get equivalent:
   -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach (controller)
   -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat (view)